# SecKeyGenerateSymmetric is generating the same key

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes

I am playing around with the `Security` framework by Apple. Reading the docs, I came across `SecKeyGenerateSymmetric`, which is used for generating a random symmetric key, given a set of `CFMutableDictionaryRef` parameters.
So, I tried generating a 128 bit AES key, with some custom paramters, here's the code:

```
SecKeyRef key;

CFMutableDictionaryRef parameters = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeyTypeAES);

int32_t rawnum = 128;
CFNumberRef num = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &rawnum);
CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits, num);

CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrIsPermanent, kCFBooleanTrue);

CFErrorRef *error;
key = SecKeyGenerateSymmetric(parameters, error);
```

So, as you can see, I specified with `CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrIsPermanent, kCFBooleanTrue);` that the key should be saved in the keychain. Upon execution, everything works fine, and the key is saved. I, however, noticed that when running the program multiple times (I tested from Xcode) the key added to the keychain is the **same** (I have verified by exporting the key and watching the raw key data).

But, if I close Xcode, reopen it, and execute the code again, the key is different. So I guess that the `SecKeyRef` object gets stored in memory, and if I call `SecKeyGenerateSymmetric` multiple times the key gets fetched from memory? If so, how can I re-set the key object to create multiple keys?

Thanks in advance if you can help me out!

---

**EDIT 1**

I wrote this function, to generate more keys:

```
void _generateKey(NSString *keyLabel) {

    SecKeyRef key;

    CFMutableDictionaryRef parameters = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeyTypeAES);

    int32_t rawnum = 128;
    CFNumberRef num = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &rawnum);
    CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits, num);

    CFStringRef yourFriendlyCFString = (__bridge CFStringRef)keyLabel;

    CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrLabel, yourFriendlyCFString);

    CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrIsPermanent, kCFBooleanTrue);

    CFErrorRef *error;
    key = SecKeyGenerateSymmetric(parameters, error);

}
```

But if I call it twice with two different labels in `main` it generates only the first key.

---

**EDIT 2**

Solved the problem by placing a `sleep` function between the two calls, works without any problem now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a *permanent* key twice, using the same `kSecAttrLabel` (the default is `NULL` according to the Apple documentation). Now as this key will be mapped to the same location, it's probably a good thing that you don't overwrite an existing key. To create multiple keys, use different labels. If you want to re-create the same key you should first `SecItemDelete` the key and then recreate it.

Comment: Note that this answer is based on my experience with crypto API's such as PKCS#11 and NSS, which this API seems to mimic.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help, but nothing seems to change. Check the question for more details.

Comment: Nevermind, you were right. I solved it by adding a `sleep(5)` call between the two calls, this way it generates both of the keys.

Comment: Now that's just weird. But I am glad it got solved anyway! Not sure if you are using a simulator, but simulators may sometimes have fun effects on e.g. random number generation, date/time and of course persistence. So that's something to keep in mind while playing with crypto in general. PS this accept earned me the first silver badge for AES ever awarded :)

Comment: Yeah, it is weird. I re-tested it now and it works even with a `sleep(1)`. Very strange indeed!